# Spring MVC form backing object has null attributes when not bound

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa

I have found many questions that are close to mine but the discussion always lead back to the same solution (DTO Approach). The problem I am facing is the following:

I have the following backing object for a form as a list of JPA entities:

```
public class PlayerForm {
private List<Player> players;

public List<Player> getPlayers() {
    return players;
}

public void setPlayers(List<Player> players) {
    this.players = players;
}

}
```

Which is a list of the following object:

```
@Entity
public class Player implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public enum PlayerType{
    DEV, POQA;
}
@Id
private Long id;
@Column(unique=true)
private String name;
private int score;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private PlayerType playerType;


@ManyToMany
private List<Bonus> bonusItems;
```

I pass a PlayerForm to the model and bind it using the forllowing form in my view:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="${action}"
modelAttribute="playerForm">
<table class="${cssClass}">
    <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${playerForm.players}" var="player" varStatus="status">
        <tr>
            <td class="center">${status.count}</td>
            <td>${player.name}</td>
            <td><input name="players[${status.index}].id" type="hidden"
                value="${player.id}" /><input name="players[${status.index}].name" type="hidden"
                value="${player.name}" /><input name="players[${status.index}].score" type="number"
                value="${player.score}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
<input style="width: 25%;" onclick="clearPreviousMessages();"
    type="submit" value="Submit Changes" />
</form:form>
```

After submitting the form, attributes that are not mapped to a form input are nulled. I know i can use a DTO abstraction of my entity and this will solve the problem. However, is there a way for spring mvc to only bind the values of my inputs to attributes while maintaining the intial values of the other attributes passed to the model even though they are not bound to any input?

Comment: No, if you want to simply update some properties you'll need to fetch the list of players and iterate over it and set the properties manually.

Comment: You dont need a DTO, but you have to understand that objects, including ModelAttributes, are nulled out between requests UNLESS you set them in Session.  Without your form bean in session, how is Spring to know what to fill in the non-posted items with?  You either have to send the WHOLE thing or put it in session.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by CodeChimp, you need to initially load the full *PlayerForm* instance and persists its state between the requests. You do this typically by using the session, but Spring MVC has a *@SessionAttributes* construct that helps you maintain a state of a model attribute between the subsequent request while within the scope of the controller.

To try to illustrate it with the following meta-code example

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("playerForm")
public class FormController {

    @RequestMapping("/init")
    public String start(Model model) {
        PlayerForm playerForm = initialiaze(); // e.g. load from DB
        model.addAttribute("playerForm", playerForm);
        return "form"; // return to the form
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processSubmit(@ModelAttribute("playerForm") PlayerForm playerForm) {
        // do something, make changes, store in DB, whatever
        return "form"; // return to the form
    }

    @RequestMapping("/finishEdit")
    public String end(SessionStatus status) {
        status.setComplete(); // remove the model attribute from the session
        return "nextpage"; // move to a different page
    }
}
```

Initially your form page is loaded on */init* and the *PlayerForm* object is initialized and added to the model, your form renders with all the data.

Changing data and submitting the form is handled by processSubmit, but before the method is called, due to the bound made by *@SessionAttributes("playerForm")* and *@ModelAttribute("playerForm")* the playerForm will get the previous values from the session, than get updated with the values from the form, finally, will change the values in the session back again, and render the form again. This loop will make all your subsequent request work as intended (no nulls will be created)

Finally, when navigating away from the page with the form, *status.setComplete* should be set so that the model attribute is removed from the session